# Why can't an attribute have the same name as a class if its type is a union and uses a default value?

Tags: python, python-typing

There seems to be some ambiguity in how the use of `|` in attribute type annotations together with attribute default values is parsed. Leading to the following error:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> class B:
...   A: A | None = None
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in B
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

If we rename the class `A` to something else it works.

Why does this not parse correctly?

Comment: It's not ambiguous, it's just resolved in a different order than you want. Also, shadowing class names with variable names is bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class definition creates a [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), and by placing `A` on the left side of an assignment the compiler binds `A` as a local name to the `None` object in the namespace of the class `B`, instead of looking up `A` outside the scope of the class `B` and binding `A` to the class `A` defined in the module namespace. So `A | None` gets evaluated as `None | None`, and since the type of `None`, `NoneType`, doesn't support the `|` operation, you get the said `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical problem with namespaces. Inside the namespace of the class, you have

```
A: [typehint] = None
```

which sets `A` to None. So where the type hint says `A | None`, it is parsed as `None | None` because inside that namespace, `A` now evaluates to None.

There are various ways to avoid this that involve not trying to use in a type hint a name that you are setting to None in the same namespace.

A simple way is to use another name in the type hint:

```
OptionalA = A | None

class B:
    A: OptionalA = None
```

This is effectively identical to what you tried, except that it doesn't directly reference the name A in the type hint, so it doesn't incur this particular problem.